# What to do if Shabbat candles go out

Tags: halacha, shabbat, weather, candle-lighting

What should a lady do if, after kindling the candles, a gust of wind blows them out, or they tip over and are extinguished?

Answer (score 6):

- If she just lit them but didn't yet say the bracha, and it's still before sunset, she hasn't yet accepted Shabbat.  So relight them and then make the bracha.
- If she already made the bracha but it's still before sunset, she can't relight them because she accepted Shabbat.  But if her husband is still home and hasn't accepted Shabbat yet for himself (he usually does that at shul), he can relight them.
- If everyone around has accepted Shabbat, or if it's sunset or later, then they have to be left alone.  If this happens, I've heard many people will relight them Saturday night (after Shabbos is over).

Comment: Shalom, If you can provide sources for your recommendations, especially the first two, that'd be great. You are, after all, talking about someone playing with fire here.

Comment: Shalom, if it is still Bein Hash'mashos, I remember learning that she should ask a gentile to rilight them.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the custom of relighting them Saturday night after shabbos is over.  My understanding is the purpose of lighting the shabbos candles is to provide light for shabbos.  Once shabbos is over, the purpose is gone.

Comment: @Dennis It could be part of _Melaveh Malka_, that is, honoring the end of the Sabbath too.

Comment: Those candles on Saturday night are called sholom bayis licht and a lot of people light them every week. I've never heard of people lighting them just because the candles went out on Friday, although it's not impossible that some do.