# Shabbos Candles That Went Out On Shabbos - Relighting Them After Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, minhag, candle-lighting

I have heard that some have the custom to relight after Shabbos any Shabbos candles that went out on Friday night. What is the source for this custom if any?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/what-to-do-if-shabbat-candles-go-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Toras Chaim (Sofer) או"ח רס"ג סק"ד brings the custom of relighting candles that went out on Shabbos.

For further reference  see- פסקי תשובות סימן רס"ג אות ז